# How to close the frame number near the footer in the listings environment

Tags: xetex

I'm using listings to format blocks of code in my xeLaTeX.I found that when I insert a piece of code, the output image will generate a number in the bottom footer. When I insert this picture into Anki's card, it will open a long, large blank.
Following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,listings}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{comments}{HTML}{868686}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\definecolor{chartreuse}{RGB}{127,255,0}
\definecolor{drakgreen}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{238,239,240}


\lstset{
    language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{comments}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,

    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    captionpos=t,
    belowcaptionskip=0em,
    belowskip=0em,

    literate=
            *{\{}{{\textcolor{darkred}{\{}}}{1}
            {\}}{{\textcolor{darkred}{\}}}}{1}
            {[}{{\textcolor{darkred}{[}}}{1}
            {]}{{\textcolor{darkred}{]}}}{1},
}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
     language=[LaTeX]Tex,
     extendedchars=true, 
     breaklines=true,
     breakatwhitespace=true,
     basicstyle=\ttfamily,
     numbers=none,

     keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},
     keywordstyle=[2]\color{blue},
     keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkblue},
     keywordstyle=[4]\color{drakgreen},
     alsoletter = {!},
     keywords=[2]{definecolor,node,addplot},
     keywords=[3]{usepackage},
     keywords=[4]{begin,end,document,figure,figure*,axis}
 }

\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}
\newtcblisting{mycode}{
      arc=0mm,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=3mm,
      right=0mm,
      width=\textwidth,
      boxrule=1pt,
      colback=lightgray,
      listing only,
      listing options={style=mystyle},
      breakable
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mycode}
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
We are working on
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}.
\end{document}
\end{mycode}
We are working on
\end{document}
```

It generates such an image：
[image]

How do I close the frame number near the footer so that the resulting image size is appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, which frame number are you referring to? The page number?

Comment: The bottommost one

Comment: This is the page number, I think. If you want to shrink your page, use the geometry package, or use the standalone class.

Comment: If used geometry package, the longer code segment will be split into multiple blocks.